# Missing space in 512 SSD disk size (not partition size)

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

I recently purchase an 512 SSD notebook and I verify that there was much less space than I thought.

I checked at the disk size (not partition size neither file system space) and I found that the disk itself does have only 476,81GB.

[image]

What is the cause for it? Where are the missing space?
The SSD is Samsung mzmte512hmhp.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to manufacturers using 1000 bytes as the size of a kilobyte, while in reality it is 1024 bytes. This issue has existed for quite a while now and is considered industry standard.

 See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive#Units

Comment: Indeed. 512 [GB] * 1000³ / 1024³ = 476,84 [GiB].